# Error: "The Visual Studio Community 2017 product is already installed in this folder. Need to choose a different location."

Tags: visual-studio

Win 7x64.

Made by:
- installed `visual studio 2017 community`;
- deleted `visual studio 2017 community`;
- deleted the folder `c: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio \ 2017 \ Community \`;

I try to install again `visual studio 2017 community`.
I get the error:
`The Visual Studio Community 2017 product is already installed in
this folder. Need to choose a different location.`

**Question.**
1. How to install the `visual studio 2017 community` back into the `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\` folder?
[image]

**Update - 1.**
I ran `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe`;
Moved to `Visual Studio Community 2017`;
Clicked `Install`;
Moved to the tab `Installation location`;

**Question.**
How to perform a "cleaning installation"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if you can run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe` and cleanup instalation. If not change instalation directory.

Comment: @DanielSęk Updated question - `Update - 1`
I do not understand what "cleaning installation" means.
How to perform a "cleaning installation"?

Comment: On my computer it looks like this: [http://danielsek.pl/stackoverflow/vs_installer.png](http://danielsek.pl/stackoverflow/vs_installer.png). There are: Update, Run, More, Repair, Uninstall, Modify. Find out which option will work for you. If installer doesn't see any installed product, you probalby have to install it in another location or hunt registry for stale entries.

Comment: @DanielSęk Do you think any of these links will help?
**1.** [How To Install and Cleanup Visual Studio 2017 Instances](http://www.cazzulino.com/install-cleanup-visual-studio.html) 
**2.** [Cleaning up corrupt Visual Studio instances](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/cleaning-up-corrupt-visual-studio-instances/) 
**3.** [Force uninstall Visual Studio 2017](https://jessehouwing.net/visual-studio-2017-force-uninstall/)